# Как правильно сделать Multy get выборку из Elasticsearch php?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Осваиваю Elasticsearch на php клиенте.

Как можно найти множество документов в ES, по id, еквивалентно "WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,9)" в SQL?

Для моно гета я делаю так

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'my_index',
    'type' => 'my_type',
    'id' => 'my_id'
  ];

  $response = $client->get($params);
```

как вытащить несколько записей?
Пытался так, но это не работает

```
    $params = [[
        'index' => 'my_index',
        'type' => 'my_type',
        'id' => 'my_id'
      ],
      [
        'index' => 'my_index',
        'type' => 'my_type',
        'id' => 'my_id2'
      ]];

  $response = $client->mget($params);
```

и так

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'my_index',
    'type' => 'my_type',
    'id' => array('my_id','my_id2')
  ];

  $response = $client->mget($params);
```

В API по PHP есть только https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/2.0/_getting_documents.html

Вот это вроде оно, только в CURL запросе https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/docs-multi-get.html

Answer (score 1):

API у эластиксерча одно, а для php - это библиотека-клиент.

Все виды запросов эластиксерча лежат в соответствующем разделе https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-queries.html

Вот есть ids query, возможно это то что вам нужно https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-ids-query.html

Answer (score 0):

```
 $response = $client->search(
      [
        'body' => [
          'query' => [
            'filtered' => [ 
              'query' => [ 'match_all' => [] ],
              'filter' => [
                'ids' => [
                  'type' => 'my_type',
                  'values' => ['my_id','my_id2']
                ]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
);
```